# Mongoose, have only one document in the collection have a true value for a boolean attribute

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am looking for ways to elegantly implemently the following update constraint:

```
var artifactSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

pid: String,
pname: String,
version: Number,
active: Boolean,
date_of_modification: Date,

tags: [String],

data: String
```

})

I would like that only document in the collection has a 'true' for the active field. An artifact can have mutliple versions and the baseline version is the one whose active == true.

Comment: Might be better to have a second collection with just one document that contains the `_id` of the single active artifact doc.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of goofy, but you can use a unique, [sparse](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-sparse/) index:

```
> db.artifacts.ensureIndex({ "active" : 1 }, { "sparse" : 1, "unique" : 1 })
```

Uniqueness ensures only one document in the collection can have a `true` value in the `active` field. Sparseness ensures multiple documents can have no `active` field set. A side effect is at most one document can have a `false` value in `active`.

For tons of useful advice about versioning in MongoDB, check out [askasya.com](http://askasya.com/archive).

Comment: I would like all the non active artifacts to have their active field set to false as most of client code requires this. Sparse indexes seem useful to other parts of my project though

Comment: Can't use this trick then, unfortunately. You'll have to enforce the restriction in client code.